# Does a creature enlarging in a Bag of Holding get crushed or pop out?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

If a player Polymorphs a Large creature into a Small creature, puts it in a Bag of Holding and closes it to suffocate it, then what happens when the creature polymorphs back into its original shape? We have read opinions that the Bag can only be opened from the outside.

Does the enlarging creature get crushed inside the extra-dimensional space or does it just pop out of the Bag?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate somewhere): [What happens when Daern's Instant Fortress expands into a space that's too small?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101901/41726), [What happens when Wild Shape/Polymorph runs out in a space that's too small?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67501/41726), [What happens when polymorph ends in a demiplane that is too small for the creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123243/41726)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## The Bag would be destroyed.

The item description states:

> If the bag is **overloaded**, pierced, or torn, it ruptures and is
>   destroyed, and its contents are scattered in the Astral Plane.

In this case, the bag would almost certainly become overloaded. It would rupture - and would be destroyed. The creature would be placed somewhere on the Astral Plane. The amount of damage, if any, is unspecified and would be up to the DM.