# What happens when a Shapechanged Dragon enters an Antimagic Field inside a narrow space?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size

A rather simple question: if an Ancient Dragon uses it's Shapechange ability to transform into a medium-sized humanoid, and then has that Shapechange disabled/dispelled inside a narrow tunnel / small underground room, will they get crushed to death by their own size?
I have plans on True Poly-ing my spellcaster PC into a Dragon, and i'm worried that a random dispel would instakill me when i go dungeon-delving in the Abyss or somewhere.

Comment: Related: "[What happens when Wild Shape/Polymorph runs out in a space that's too small?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67501)" and "[What happens when polymorph ends in a demiplane that is too small for the creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123243)" and "[Polymorph Ending in Forcecage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99661)" and "[What happens to the target of a Reduce spell if they are in a small container when the spell wears off?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142260)"

Comment: And "[Does a creature enlarging in a Bag of Holding get crushed or pop out?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123943)" and "[What happens when the Daern's Instant Fortress magic item expands into a space that's too small?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101901)" and "[What would happen if somebody ate a wild-shaped Druid, and then the Druid changed back inside them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73348)" and "[If a creature's size suddenly increases while it is inside a very small Sphere of Force (from Wall of Force) what happens?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114678)"